# how to setup a LSTM network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement an LSTM network using Keras to predict the movement of a bounding box given an action.

The dataset I am using looks like this: (the bounding box to predict is made out of the columns b0, b1, b2, b3)

```
act b0  b1  b2  b3  id  score

0   85  238 129 256 69  0.9289865493774414
1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
3   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
0   46  136 256 245 73  0.9369892477989197
1   18  18  256 252 73  0.8203921318054199
1   144 212 169 223 10  0.9630357623100281
1   13  9   252 199 73  0.9374213814735413
3   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
0   215 141 255 233 72  0.9941028952598572
2   199 116 243 183 74  0.8685483932495117
3   215 141 255 233 72  0.9941184520721436
1   189 78  215 95  76  0.8610376119613647
3   206 50  255 169 72  0.8224002122879028
0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
3   19  129 249 253 73  0.8635225892066956
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
2   0   78  13  91  10  0.9488454461097717
3   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
0   206 123 255 189 62  0.9980332255363464
2   221 197 256 255 62  0.9782524704933167
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
0   184 78  243 169 72  0.9953457713127136
2   191 139 254 246 72  0.9929528832435608
3   184 78  243 169 72  0.9953963160514832
3   197 1   254 91  72  0.9956125020980835
2   184 78  243 169 72  0.9953963160514832
```

I am creating a new column to have the bounding box in a single input with:

```
b_box = ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']
df['b_box'] = df[b.box].apply(tuple, axis=1).apply(list)
```

### The issue I am facing:

Doing this is that the shape of the value I am passing to the LSTM network is a 4D array `(3994, 5, 1, 4)` which it cannot be used.

#### Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import numpy as np

PATH = "./csv/"

filename = os.path.join(PATH, "test.csv")
names = ['act', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'id', 'score']
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')

# print("Starting file:")
# print(df[0:10])
# print("Ending file:")
# print(df[-10:])
b_box = ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3']


df['b_box'] = df[b_box].apply(tuple, axis=1).apply(list)

# print(df.head())

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)

boxes_train = train['b_box'].tolist()
boxes_test = test['b_box'].tolist()

# print("Training set has {} observations".format(len(boxes_train)))
# print("Test set has {} observations".format(len(boxes_test)))

def to_sequences(seq_size, obs):
    x = []
    y = []

    for i in range(len(obs)-SEQUENCE_SIZE-1):
        window = obs[i:(i+SEQUENCE_SIZE)]
        after_window = obs[i+SEQUENCE_SIZE]
        window = [[x] for x in window]
        x.append(window)
        y.append(after_window)

    return np.array(x), np.array(y)

SEQUENCE_SIZE = 5
x_train, y_train = to_sequences(SEQUENCE_SIZE, boxes_train)
x_test, y_test = to_sequences(SEQUENCE_SIZE, boxes_test)

print(x_train)
# print("Shape of training set: {}".format(x_train.shape))
# print("Shape of test set: {}".format(x_test.shape))

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.datasets import imdb

print("Build model...")
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print('Train...')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2, epochs=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepare your data using [TimeSeriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/). Here's a quick example with 2 features.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

dim = 1000

# 2 features 
x1 = np.random.normal(size=dim).reshape(1000,1)
x2 = np.random.normal(size=dim).reshape(1000,1)
data = np.hstack((x1,x2))

# target is simply the sum
targets = x1 + x2 
targets = np.insert(targets,0,0)[0:dim]

data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(data, targets,length=1,batch_size=1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1,2), dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')

# Please note 'fit_generator' instead of 'fit'
model.fit_generator(generator=data_gen,steps_per_epoch=32,epochs=5)
```

Out:

```
Epoch 1/5
32/32 [==============================] - 3s 89ms/step - loss: 2.6368
Epoch 2/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 1.8943
Epoch 3/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.0667
Epoch 4/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.1214
Epoch 5/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5821
```

## EDIT

In your case since you're using pandas, you have to simply extract the features and the target (I assume 'score' to be the target), and feed them into TimeseriesGenerator. The *insert* step is necessary to shift the labels one step in the future. Also the parameters *length* and batch_size are 1 cause I guess that every time step has is labelled (i.e. you're not using an entire sequence of time steps to make each prediction). Check in the documentation if these parameters are actually what you need for your model.

```
dim = 1000
# the columns are the same but I filled the df with random values 
train_cols = ['act','b0','b1','b2','b3','id']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(dim, 6)), columns=train_cols)

df['score'] = df.mean(axis=1)
targets = np.insert(np.asarray(df['score']),0,0)[0:dim]

data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(df[train_cols].values, targets,length=1,batch_size=1)
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how should I use it in my example but can't understand it.

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro edited, hope it's more clear now

Comment: I am getting this issue since the input I am passing is gained from the 4 points of the boxes that joined together it forms a list `[b0, b1, b2, b3]` (I called it `b_box` in my code). with your example should I use as a target this input?

Comment: @AlessandroCandeloro you don't need to use the function you wrote. Feeding the dataframe columns to the generator is the only thing you need to do, the generator is meant exactly to format the data in the right way for the training. About the target, you didn't write what column you're trying to predict so in the answer I assumed it to be 'score' and I used all other columns as training features. if this is not the case then just change the names in the right way. Also, pay attention to *input_shape* inside the LSTM initialisation, it has to be (1,number_of_features)

Comment: Also, I noticed you're splitting the data using sklearn. Be aware that with time data you should't randomised the dataset, the right way to split train and test in this case is to simply use the first 80% of rows for training and the last 20% for test.

Comment: I see, so in the case I want to predict the bounding box (the columns b0, b1, b2, b3 of the dataset), how can I make the targets be more than 1 column?